# How to smooth vector of 2d coordinates by gaussian smoothing (c++)?

Tags: c++, 3d, 2d, gaussian, smoothing

I have a std::vector of 2d or 3d coordinates. I need to apply gaussian smoothing to it, to get a smoothed curve.

How to do it? I can smooth vector of float values, but I don't know how to smooth multidimensial values.

Comment: How do you do it in 1d?

Comment: Do not underestimate the benefits of showing your research. It gives potential answerers a baseline they can build on from and shows people that you've invested some personal effort into the problem.

Comment: Can you give more information on your `std:vector`? An example looks like this: `std::vector<Point>` where a `Point` might be `struct Point { double X; double Y; };` or something like that. What are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You right, it's just a vector of points that has X and Y fields. Points coordinates has a noice and I want to smooth it to reduce noice and get a points of approximate curve. I can use sliding window and gaussian smooth if I have just a vector of float values, but I don't know how to deal with vector that have two float coordinates for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just smoothed each coordinate independently and it works:

```
void PathControllerGaussian::smooth_path_gaussian(FuturePath & path, unsigned future_steps)
{
    smooth_dimension_gaussian(path.pos, 0, future_steps);
    smooth_dimension_gaussian(path.pos, 1, future_steps);
    smooth_dimension_gaussian(path.pos, 2, future_steps);
}

void PathControllerGaussian::smooth_dimension_gaussian(PathVec & vec, unsigned dim_index, unsigned vec_size)
{
    float sum;

    for (unsigned i = gaussian_kernel_size / 2; i < vec_size - gaussian_kernel_size / 2; ++i)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < gaussian_kernel_size; ++j)
        {
            sum += vec[i + j - gaussian_kernel_size / 2][dim_index] * gaussian_kernel[j];
        }

        vec[i][dim_index] = sum;
    }
}

float PathControllerGaussian::gaussian(float value, float sigma)
{
    return 1 / sqrt(2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma) * std::exp(- (value * value) / (2 * sigma * sigma));
}

void PathControllerGaussian::prepare_gaussian_kernel(unsigned size, float sigma)
{
    gaussian_kernel_size = size;
    gaussian_sigma = sigma;
    gaussian_kernel.clear();

    int mid_point = gaussian_kernel_size / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < gaussian_kernel_size; ++i)
    {
        gaussian_kernel.push_back(gaussian(i - mid_point, gaussian_sigma));
    }
}
```